# {System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXXXX} failed due to the following error: 8007007e

Tags: .net, windows

I am getting the following exception while running an windows application "{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5164619A-E62E-4EC0-B207-9108907E607D} failed due to the following error: 8007007e." I have placed the registry entry and also the Dll in the particular path. Also the read permission for the particular user accessing the application to the dll is also provided. But still i am getting the above exception. please suggest any solution for the above errror?

Comment: What is the COM component (did you write it yourself, is it managed or unmanaged)? Also, why are you registering it manually?

Comment: It is a "file not found" error message for a .NET DLL.  Using a [ComVisible] .NET assembly in a .NET program is not a good idea.  Diagnose the problem with FusLogvw.exe or ProcMon.  Or contact the owner of the component for support, this is almost always an installation problem.

Comment: @  user1610015 - It is the unmanaged dll. While installation of the application the registry entries are not registered properly, because of this installation issue i am trying to register the dll manually.

Answer (score -1):

Above Error was resolved by registering dll again

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 yourdllname